# Condensing arrays in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have a query that produces strings of arrays using they `array_agg()` function

```
SELECT 
array_agg(message) as sequence
from mytable
group by id
```

which produces a table that looks like this:

```
                 sequence
1 foo foo bar baz bar baz
2     foo bar bar bar baz
3 foo foo foo bar bar baz
```

but I aim to condense the array of strings so that none can repeat more than once in a row, for example, the desired output would look like this:

```
    sequence
1 foo bar baz bar baz
2 foo bar baz
3 foo bar baz
```

How would one go about doing this with Presto SQL ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this in one of two ways:

1. Remove duplicates from the resulting arrays using the [`array_distinct`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_distinct) function:

```sql
WITH mytable(id, message) AS (VALUES
  (1, 'foo'), (1, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), (1, 'bar'), (1, 'baz'), (1, 'baz'),
  (2, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (2, 'bar'), (2, 'bar'), (2, 'baz'),
  (3, 'foo'), (3, 'foo'), (3, 'foo'), (3, 'bar'), (3, 'bar'), (3, 'baz')
)
SELECT array_distinct(array_agg(message)) AS sequence
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```

2. Use the `DISTINCT` qualifier in the aggregation to remove the duplicate values before they are passed into array_agg.

```sql
WITH mytable(id, message) AS (VALUES
  (1, 'foo'), (1, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), (1, 'bar'), (1, 'baz'), (1, 'baz'),
  (2, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (2, 'bar'), (2, 'bar'), (2, 'baz'), (3, 'foo'),
  (3, 'foo'), (3, 'foo'), (3, 'bar'), (3, 'bar'), (3, 'baz')
)
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT message) AS sequence
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```

Both alternatives produce the same result:

```
    sequence
-----------------
 [foo, bar, baz]
 [foo, bar, baz]
 [foo, bar, baz]
(3 rows)
```

**UPDATE**: You can remove repeated sequences of elements with the recently introduced [`MATCH_RECOGNIZE`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/match-recognize.html) feature:

```sql
WITH mytable(id, message) AS (VALUES
  (1, 'foo'), (1, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), (1, 'baz'), (1, 'bar'), (1, 'baz'),
  (2, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (2, 'bar'), (2, 'bar'), (2, 'baz'),
  (3, 'foo'), (3, 'foo'), (3, 'foo'), (3, 'bar'), (3, 'bar'), (3, 'baz')
)
SELECT array_agg(value) AS sequence
FROM mytable
 MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
    PARTITION BY id
    MEASURES A.message AS value
    PATTERN (A B*)
    DEFINE B AS message = PREV(message)
)
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I guess I didn't mention an important point (that I do not need distinct values, but rather non-repeating consecutive values).  I modified the first row of my data to illustrate this point

Comment: A third way for the first part of the answer: you can use `set_agg()` to get the same results. I.e: `SELECT set_agg(message) AS sequence`